# Trying to get restsharp to match curl code from postman

Tags: c#, curl, postman, restsharp

This has been asked a hundred times, but none of them seem to work for me.  I have the following curl code:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://endpoint/telemetry' \
--header 'x-ads-dev: akeyvalue' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '[
    {
        "entityID": 2123,
        "locationID": 33,
        "dataPoints": [
            {
                "dateTime": "2020-08-03 23:05:00",
                "reading": 0,
                "flags": 0,
                "quality": 0,
                "ignore": true
            },
            {
                "dateTime": "2020-09-27 03:10:00",
                "reading": 0,
                "flags": 0,
                "quality": 0,
                "ignore": true
            }
        ]
    }
]'
```

When I run this in postman I get a different response from the server than when I try to work it into restsharp.  Here is my rest sharp code:

```
try {
    string url = "https://endpoint/";
    var client = new RestClient(url);
    client.AddDefaultHeader("x-ads-dev", "akeyvalue");
    var request = new RestRequest("telemetry", Method.Post);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", datapoint, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    var response =  await client.PostAsync(request);
```

The value of the variable datapoint is:

```
[
   {
      "entityID":2123,
      "locationID":33,
      "dataPoints":[
         {
            "dateTime":"2020-08-03 23:05:00",
            "reading":0,
            "flags":0,
            "quality":0,
            "ignore":true
         },
         {
            "dateTime":"2020-09-27 03:10:00",
            "reading":0,
            "flags":0,
            "quality":0,
            "ignore":true
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

When I run it through postman with the curl code the server accepts the request, but when I run it through restsharp I get bad request error.

EDITED the code to match the below comment, as doing so didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the content type you define using the `AddParameter` is the culprit. Have you tested it like so:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", datapoint, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

or using `AddJsonBody`

```
request.AddJsonBody(datapoint);
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried both of those.  Using the curl code in postman vs restsharp still has different outcomes.

Comment: Postman has the ability to generate RestSharp code from your request. The code it generates _should_ yield an equivalent request. Apart from the fact that they use different `User-Agent` HTTP header, the server may return an BadRequest for a specific agent, but I doubt that this is the case. If the generated code does not work out for you, you may want to sniff the requests and see if there are any differences.